# How do you organize/plan your discovery session so that it does not conflict with the work of the current sprint?

Tags: scrum, agile, planning

Let's suppose you have a team of 10 developers working on automation (RPA). They are working in 4 different, independent bots.

The PO comes with more opportunities for automation. These opportunities need to be reviewed, sized and an effort estimation need to be provided, i.e. a discovery session is needed.

How do you plan a discovery session for new work items, considering:

1) The PO and involved stake holders and SMEs definitely can not spend more than 1 day on such a session

2) The ideas for automation, based on previous experience, could be completed within 1-2 sprints (1 sprint = 2 weeks)

3) The development team is already busy working in the current sprint

Do you pull some of the devs working in the current sprint to participate on this? How do you handle that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Product Backlog Refinement

> The PO comes with more opportunities for automation. These opportunities need to be reviewed, sized and an effort estimation need to be provided, i.e. a discovery session is needed.

What you're calling a "discovery session" is actually a defined event in Scrum called [Product Backlog refinement](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#artifacts-productbacklog).

> [Refinement] is an ongoing process in which the Product Owner and the Development Team collaborate on the details of Product Backlog items. During Product Backlog refinement, items are reviewed and revised. The Scrum Team decides how and when refinement is done. Refinement usually consumes no more than 10% of the capacity of the Development Team. However, Product Backlog items can be updated at any time by the Product Owner or at the Product Owner’s discretion.

Your real issue appears to be that the Scrum Team hasn't allocated sufficient time for this essential activity. This is most likely due to the 100% utilization fallacy and/or process failures during Sprint Planning.

The Scrum Team should be allocating up to 8 hours in a two-week Sprint for Backlog Refinement. This activity should always be factored into the Scrum Team's capacity planning activities, especially during Sprint Planning. In particular, the Development Team should be adjusting its forecasts to ensure sufficient capacity for *all* framework activities, including refinement. Failure to charge framework overhead to team capacity reduces transparency, and often leaves the team over-committed once the framework's activities are factored into the amount of work a team can complete in a single iteration. Agile frameworks *require* sufficient slack to remain sustainable!

### Accounting for Refinement Explicitly

If the Scrum Team lacks the process maturity to reliably scope Sprint Goals to available Sprint capacity, it may be necessary for the Product Owner to explicitly include refinement activities in the Product Backlog. This will force the Development Team to include those activities in estimates and the Sprint Backlog, and makes refinement a visible deliverable for each Sprint.

### Accounting for Refinement (and Other Activities) Implicitly

Alternatively, the Development Team's forecast could be reduced by 10% to implicitly include refinement in its Sprint Planning. For example, if the team has a sustainable average velocity of 25 without accounting for refinement, no more than 22 points should be pulled into the Sprint Backlog each Sprint.

After accounting similarly for other Scrum activities, I'd actually recommend structuring your Sprint Goals around a median of 80% of available team capacity each Sprint to ensure sufficient slack to sustain the pace of development indefinitely.

### Other Framework Considerations

There's a lot more to unpack in your question. Many of the underlying issues hinted at in your question are deserving of separate questions, but are too broad to address in depth within a single post. I'll give some of them a quick gloss here.

1. Velocity should be used primarily as a capacity planning metric after applying suitable fudge factors. It is *not* supposed to a measure of productivity or a management target, so don't use it that way.
2. Scrum values a sustainable pace of collaborative development over packing each Sprint to the brim. Don't chase utilization metrics!
3. Use capacity planning to make each Sprint an efficient time box for achieving clear goals and helping the team work *better*. Don't use the framework to force people work harder or faster; that never ends well for anyone, including the business and its customers if quality drops as a result of insufficient slack.
4. Each Sprint *must* have a Sprint Goal. Without one, you can't effectively scope work for the Sprint, consistently deliver on Sprint Goals, or routinely achieve the Development Team's forecasts.
5. Story spikes are time-boxed, exploratory user stories with results that feed effective estimation of more complex user stories and epics. As a rule of thumb, such stories should be treated as work for a future Sprint, with the results of the spike feeding refinement and planning.

   - As a general rule, the output of a story spike is an input to a Sprint Review or Backlog Refinement.
   - In most cases, story spikes shouldn't lead to additional work in the *current* Sprint.
   - Follow-on work flowing from a story spike should be placed onto the Product Backlog as future work to be estimated, prioritized, and planned for subsequent iterations.
6. [Agile release planning](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/16376/4271) is based on a sustainable cadence, and optimizes for *predictability* and *adaptation* rather than individual or team utilization metrics.
7. Fixed-scope or fixed-effort planning at the project level is not agile, and will generally result in a brittle project plan with poor product quality.

In short, the problems you're facing may not be simply the result of insufficient team capacity for refinement. It's definitely worth spending several Sprint Retrospectives (or even carving some near-term time out of a following Sprint) to inspect-and-adapt the team's processes.

### Parting Thoughts

Quoting a slide I wrote for one of my recent coaching engagements, I'll leave you with this thought:

> A misapplied Scrum framework is like a chainsaw. It's a lot more efficient at cutting down trees than a butter knife, but it's also much more likely to cause bodily harm when used improperly.

The application of agile principles doesn't require a perfect process on day one, or even day 501 of an 18-month project. The intent is to create time and opportunity for *continuous improvements* to the product, the process, and the workflow. Start where you are, and then *iterate* towards a more sustainable process!

Answer (score 6):

> The development team is already busy working in the current sprint

One of the principles in the [Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#artifacts-productbacklog) is that a Scrum team spends time during the sprint refining their backlog of work. This can represent up to 10% of the time in the sprint.

In your situation this backlog refinement would include discovery sessions, review, etc.

How the refinement is organised is up to the team.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer I have found easy to implement in many different kinds of teams: Create a user story for the discovery session, and treat it like you do any other story. That is, rank it high enough in your Product Backlog to get into the sprint; estimate and task it out (if you do those things); add the developers who choose to be involved; and if that pushes a development story out of the sprint based on your method of ensuring "sustainable pace," so be it.